# Plot two images with different X/Ydata in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to plot two images with different Xdata/Ydata in order to perform image stitching.
The solution that I performed is the following:

```
% Transform the second image using the estimated homography
T = maketform('projective', inv(H));
[~, xdata, ydata] = imtransform(im2, T);

% Compute bounds for stitched image
xdataout = [min(1, xdata(1)) max(size(im1, 2), xdata(2))];
ydataout = [min(1, ydata(1)) max(size(im1, 1), ydata(2))];
% Transform both images with the computed xdata and ydata
im2t = imtransform(im2, T, 'XData', xdataout, 'YData', ydataout);
T2 = maketform('affine', eye(3));
im1t = imtransform(im1, T2,'XData', xdataout, 'YData', ydataout);

% Merge the two images 
result = max(im1t, im2t); 
figure, imshow(result)
```

However in this way I am placing in the foreground the image with higher luminance. I have instead to put in the foreground the reference image (im1).
I have tried as follows:

```
result = im1t; 
result(result == 0) = im2t(result == 0);
```

but in this way an artifact appears in the top border of im1t (there appears a sort of black border). I suppose that this is due to the affine transformation that I performed in order to register the two images. 
Thanks in advance

edit:
I finally solved the issues using 'FillValues', NaN as parameter in imtransform

Comment: Your question is? Also, might be useful if you could attach the images.

Comment: I thought the question was clear: I need to put in the foreground the reference image, and to use the second image only to cover areas not covered by the first image, and I don't know how to do it, because I failed in my attempts.
Unfortunately I don't have the needed reputation to attach images, the two images that I need to stitch are the following:
http://www.dsi.unive.it/~atorsell/Visione/stitching/Rainier1.png
http://www.dsi.unive.it/~atorsell/Visione/stitching/Rainier2.png

Comment: sure: the result using max produces the following: http://wwwstud.dsi.unive.it/gbasei/tmp/untitled.jpg as you can see the image with higher luminance is in the foreground. in this case it is correct, but if I use im2 as reference image I want that im2 is on the foreground
the failed attempt that I described above produces the following result:
http://wwwstud.dsi.unive.it/gbasei/tmp/fail.jpg

Comment: That looks quite good actually. The black regions _will_ appear because the information for those parts of the scene is not available.

Comment: the issue regards the artifact on the top border of im1, as you can see there is a little visible black border that does not appears when I'm using max. I edited the previous comment

Comment: Ah I see. That seems to be some sort of aliasing. Have you tried `result = im1t; 
result(result < thresh) = im2t(result < thresh);` where thresh is some low-ish intensity?

Comment: Well, setting as threshold sqrt(2) gives me the expected result. but sqrt(2) is a high threshold in my opinion :/ however as temp fix it could work for me, thanks

Comment: It's not that high in my opinion. With aliasing effects visible and a range of [0,255], any threshold up to around 5 isn't too bad from whatever I know.